# Can we have INSTALL_REFERRER two times in a single Android app?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application where I am using `INSTALL_REFERRER` to know source of installation of my app. For this, I am using first `Google Analytics` Install_Referrer intent filter and one of my own custom ones.

Is it possible to have two broadcast receiver entries with an intent filter `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` in Android?

Google Analytics Receiver

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My Custom Broadcast Receiver.

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.xyz.broadcastreceiver.ReferrerCatcher"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/how-can-i-use-multiple-install-trackers-with-the-android-library

Comment: Above article only works when you are going to have 2 or more custom receivers, for example, one to handle Google Analytics broadcast, one to handle other broadcasts. But in your case, you only need to handle broadcast from Google Analytics. So, one broadcast receiver is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No we can't have two Install Referrer broadcast receiver. For this I created my own custom broadcast receiver to achieve Google Analytics Source tracking and my own stuff.

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.xyz.broadcastreceiver.ReferrerCatcher"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In the `ReferrerCatcher` broadcast receiver

```
public class ReferrerCatcher extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String TAG = InstallReceiver.class.getCanonicalName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Google Analytics
        new CampaignTrackingReceiver().onReceive(context, intent);

        Log.d(TAG, intent.getExtras().getString("referrer");
        // my stuff here 
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to print/log the values of a referrerString?Also, could you please give any info about sending a postback from the app.Thanks

Comment: Please provide any source, that you can not have two or more receiver with intent-filter INSTALL_REFERRER. Due to merged manifest there could be a lot of receivers with the same intent-filter. I doubt that they all won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working in a similar application, and after doing some research I found that we could just remove **Google Analytics Receiver** (as it does nothing), and use your own custom receiver instead. And of course you could still have your app send data to Google Analytics by implementing below code:

```
public enum TrackerName {
    APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
    GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
    ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
}

HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker("UA-xxxxxxxx-1")
                : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
                : analytics.newTracker("UA-xxxxxxxx-1");
        mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
    } return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}

// Get tracker.
Tracker t = getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

// Set screen name.
t.setScreenName("some string");

// Send a screen view.
t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

**EDIT:**

Below code shows how I declare the broadcast receiver in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement-->;
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
<receiver android:name=".app.service.CustomReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```